# Get MD5 String from Message Digest

Tags: java, md5, message, digest

I understand how it works but if I want to print out the MD5 as String how would I do that?

```
public static void getMD5(String fileName) throws Exception{
    InputStream input =  new FileInputStream(fileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    int read;
    do {
        read = input.read(buffer);
        if (read > 0) {
            hash.update(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } while (read != -1);
    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this

```
StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] hash = md.digest();

for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
    if ((0xff & hash[i]) < 0x10) {
        hexString.append("0"
                + Integer.toHexString((0xFF & hash[i])));
    } else {
        hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & hash[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note also that StringBuilder can be now used instead of StringBuffer, cons and pros of each are discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer

Answer (score 79):

You can get it writing less:

```
String hex = (new HexBinaryAdapter()).marshal(md5.digest(YOUR_STRING.getBytes()))
```

Comment: Do you know if there are any performance considerations here?  Assuming we reused a single HexBinaryAdapter, would this introduce any significant overheads compared to doing the bit operations ourselves?  We need to use this code a lot as we use the MD5 for URLs as the key into our image cache.

Comment: Java's source is public. :)


`HexBinaryAdapter.marshal()` only calls `DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary()` (you can actually use that instead, if you want to avoid instantiating a `HexBinaryAdapter`), which in turn instantiates a singleton `DatatypeConverterImpl` the first time it's called.


After that, it's just a straight call to `DatatypeConverterImpl`'s `printHexBinary`. It uses a method pretty similar to WhiteFang34's answer.

Comment: HexBinaryAdapter is not in JDK9

Answer (score 29):

```
    String input = "168";
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] md5sum = md.digest(input.getBytes());
    String output = String.format("%032X", new BigInteger(1, md5sum));
```

or

```
DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary( MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest("a".getBytes("UTF-8")))
```

Comment: DatatypeConverter is not in JDK9

Comment: @user1133275 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j

Comment: yah I was just looking at that temporary hack for a lib, but for this question answers that do not depend on deprecated code are better.

Comment: BigInteger seems to have an issue when the leading hex digit is 0.

Answer (score 23):

You can also use Apache Commons Codec library.
This library includes methods `public static String md5Hex(InputStream data)` and `public static String md5Hex(byte[] data)` in the `DigestUtils` class.
No need to invent this yourself ;)

Answer (score 9):

First you need to get the `byte[]` output of the `MessageDigest`:

```
byte[] bytes = hash.digest();
```

You can't easily print this though (with e.g. `new String(bytes)`) because it's going to contain binary that won't have good output representations. You can convert it to hex for display like this however:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 * bytes.length);
for (byte b : bytes) {
    sb.append("0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4));
    sb.append("0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((b & 0x0F)));
}
String hex = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the actual problem, and what would come as a first thought in byte-string which is to just use the string constructor. Also, I'm surprised no one suggested Base64. How does Base64 compare to these HexToBinary answers.

Comment: Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3183880/1364747

Answer (score 7):

Shortest way:

```
String toMD5(String input) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] raw = md.digest(input.getBytes());
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(raw);
}
```

Just remember to handle the exception.

Answer (score 4):

With the byte array, result from message digest:

```
...
byte hashgerado[] = md.digest(entrada);
...

for(byte b : hashgerado)
    System.out.printf("%02x", Byte.toUnsignedInt(b));
```

Result (for example):
89e8a9f68ad3c4bba9b9d3581cf5201d

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * hashes:
 * e7cfa2be5969e235138356a54bad7fc4
 * 3c9ec110aa171b57bb41fc761130822c
 *
 * compiled with java 8 - 12 Dec 2015
 */
public static String generateHash() {
    long r = new java.util.Random().nextLong();
    String input = String.valueOf(r);
    String md5 = null;

    try {
        java.security.MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        //Update input string in message digest
        digest.update(input.getBytes(), 0, input.length());
        //Converts message digest value in base 16 (hex)
        md5 = new java.math.BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16);
    }
    catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return md5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI...

In certain situations this did not work for me

```
md5 = new java.math.BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16);
```

but this did

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
    if ((0xff & digest[i]) < 0x10) {
        sb.append("0").append(Integer.toHexString((0xFF & digest[i])));
    } else {
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digest[i]));
    }
}

String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @WillBerger ! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

Call `hash.digest()` to finish the process. It will return an array of bytes.

You can create a String from a `byte[]` using a String constructor, however if you want a hex string you'll have to loop through the byte array manually and work out the characters.

Answer (score -2):

This is another version of @anything answer:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
    if ((0xff & digest[i]) < 0x10) {
        sb.append("0").append(Integer.toHexString((0xFF & digest[i])));
    } else {
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digest[i]));
    }
}

String result = sb.toString();
```