# What kind of hashing / encryption is this?

Tags: java, encryption, hash

```
private String getString(byte[] bytes)
   {
     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
     {
       byte b = bytes[i];
       sb.append(0xFF & b);
     }
     return sb.toString();
   }

   public String encrypt(String source)
   {
     try
     {
       MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
       byte[] bytes = md.digest(source.getBytes());
       return getString(bytes);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
       e.printStackTrace(); }
     return null;
   }
```

If my text = "test"
The First Part toString()) produces a value of "Encryption$2@6966b26b"
And the second part then gets that and produces a value of "91431072057033211115202222781313839180246"
But why is the md5 a number and not 31f521a06d5060d1f38159c74a1f7cf2 or something similar?

Comment: It literally says MD5 in the code...

Comment: The numeric presentation is because you get a number of bytes back. If you want it represented in hex like 31f521a06d5060d1f38159c74a1f7cf2 you need to convert your bytes to 16-base. so a value between 00-ff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clearly stated in code yuou are using MD5 hashing algorithm

Now your question is why:

> But why is the md5 a number and not 31f521a06d5060d1f38159c74a1f7cf2 or something similar?

your answer is simple, look at code which generates you string from your byte array.

```
  byte b = bytes[i];
  sb.append(0xFF & b);
```

you take byte, ie 0x20 then you perform logical and operation with integer 0x255 and then you add decimal representation of result yo your StringBuilder.
What you want to do is more like

```
sb.append(Integer.toHexString(0xff&b));
```

Comment: Any way to convert the original to HexString?

Answer (score 1):

The function "encrypt()" returns a MD5 hash. You should rename it to "hash", because hashing != encrypting.
If you want to encrypt a string, you can look here: https://gist.github.com/bricef/2436364

Comment: But why is the md5 a number and not 31f521a06d5060d1f38159c74a1f7cf2 or something similar?

Comment: I found this: [MD5 Digest](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5470219/get-md5-string-from-message-digest)

Answer (score 0):

I would say MD5 hash, because the code says `MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")` :D

Comment: But why is the md5 a number and not 31f521a06d5060d1f38159c74a1f7cf2 or something similar?